# TSQL BULK INSERT row errors cause C# exceptions

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv, ado.net

I am processing extremely large delimited files.  These files have been pre-processed to ensure that field and row delimiters are valid.  Occasionally a row is processed that fails TSQL constraints (usually a datatype issue).  'Fixing' the input data is not an option in this case.

We use `MAXERRORS` to set an acceptable number of input errors and `ERRORFILE` to log failed rows.

The bulk insert completes in SSMS with severity level 16 error messages logged to the messages window for each failed row.  Attempting to execute this code via the C# `SqlCommand` class causes an exception to be thrown when the first severity level 16 error message is generated, causing the batch to fail.

Is there a way to complete the operation and ignore SQL error messages via C# and something like SqlCommand?

Example Command:

```
BULK INSERT #some-table FROM 'filename' 
WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR ='\0',ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',FIRSTROW = 2, MAXERRORS = 100, ERRORFILE = 'some-file')
```

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS?

Comment: @HLGEM We're using SQL 2008 Express.  My understanding is that SSIS at that level lacks the functionality I would need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), and then capture the rows copied using the [SqlRowsCopied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied.aspx) event.  This will more closely mimic the `BULK INSERT` T-SQL command.

**EDIT**: It looks like the error handling isn't that robust with SqlBulkCopy.  However, here is an example that seems to do what you're looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387465/Retrieving-failed-records-after-an-SqlBulkCopy-exc

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET support all the datatype as SQL you should be able to TryParse in .NET to catch any conversion errors.  On date you also need to test for within the SQL data range.  On text need to test length.  I do exactly this on some very large inserts were I parse down some CSV.   TryParse is pretty fast.   Better than a Try Catch as it does not have the overhead of throwing and error.

And why not insert in .NET C#.   There is a class for bulkcopy.   I use TVP asynch insert while parsing and do 10,000 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that an exception is thrown for each row that has an error but is just counted by SQL.  However, it is also passed back to C# (SSIS in my case). I found that wrapping the bulk insert with TRY/CATCH logic and using THROW (to re-throw the exceptions) when more than MAXERRORS occur, works for me.

BEGIN TRY
BULK INSERT #some-table FROM 'filename'
WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR ='\0',ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',FIRSTROW = 2, MAXERRORS = 100,
ERRORFILE = 'some-file')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
THROW;
END CATCH